# Android Studio and Google Maps API fragment Crash

Tags: android, maps, key, fragment

I want to create a google map but I have a problem with it. 
It crashes when I start it, I also created that API Key and inserted in "YOUR_KEY_HERE" but it still doesn't work. It might be a problem with fragment tag? I tried to make another application with fragment but it also crashes. Thank you. (Android studio 3.1.3)

Comment: show your code for the map implementation

Comment: share your code

Comment: i just selected the "Activity" Google Map,i didnt write any code :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe that we were having the same issue. I would launch a clean version of a Google Maps Activity, go grab a new API Key, and run the application. When I did this, it would pop up then immediately crash. I had to go into my Manifest and add `<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>` in the application Section to resolve this issue.

Hope this helps!